# How to get value of {} in shell?

Tags: shell, find, xargs

```
find . -name "*.network" -o -name "*.index" | xargs -n 1 -I {} -P 5 sh -c "ncols=3; filename={}; echo $filename"
```

I want get the filename stored in a variable. By setting filename={}, and echo filename, I got nothing output in console.

Since I want to use multi-thread. xargs is necessary in my script.

I use single quotes as suggested by aicastell. But I want to used awk inside quotes. What should I do with single quotes inside quotes? \s did not work.

Can anybody help me with this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since `$filename` is within double quotes, the shell substitues it before it already before it runs your pipe. With other words: The *filename* in the `echo` statement refers to the variable in the calling shell, not in the subshell which you open with `sh -c`.

Hence, use single quotes instead!

Comment: Thanks a lot. The script went well with your suggestions.

Comment: I want to use awk command inside the single quotes. I tried \' and it didn't work. Is there any method to do this?

Comment: (1) "Didn't work" is a poor description. We can't help until you explain in detail, in what way it did not work. (2) I don't see any awk command in your posting. If you talking about a new problem, please make a new post.

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like this:

```
for FILENAME in $(find . -name "*.network" -o -name "*.index")
do
   # process $FILENAME
done
```

Comment: This works. But I am trying to optimize the script using multi-thread. That is why I use xargs

Comment: If you have requirements related with your question (multi-threading), maybe should be useful adding them to your original issue. However, nice to see somebody else solved it yet! :)